# How to find currently focused ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

Sometimes I find WPF a bit frustrating - is there a way to find the currently active `ListBox` in a `UserControl` from the `UserControl` itself?

What I want to do is have a property in my `UserControl` that returns the `ListBox` that is currently focused within the `UserControl`.

I've tried this:

```
public ListBox FocusedListBox
{
    if (listBox1.IsFocused)
        return listBox1;
    if (listBox2.IsFocused)
        return listBox2;
    return null;
}
```

This doesn't work. Neither does this:

```
public ListBox FocusedListBox
{
    if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) == listBox1)
        return listBox1;
    if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) == listBox2)
        return listBox2;
    return null;
}
```

Or this:

```
public ListBox FocusedListBox
{
    if (Keyboard.FocusedElement == listBox1)
        return listBox1;
    if (Keyboard.FocusedElement == listBox2)
        return listBox2;
    return null;
}
```

So *how do I do this*??

---

Based on Jason Boyd's answer I actually found a solution. And I must say that all this is very little intuitive... -.-

```
public ListBox FocusedListBox
{
    get
    {
        var currentObject = Keyboard.FocusedElement as DependencyObject;

        while (currentObject != null && currentObject != this && currentObject != Application.Current.MainWindow)
        {
            if (currentObject == listBox1|| currentObject == listBox2)
            {
                return currentObject as ListBox;
            }
            else
            {
                currentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentObject);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your `ListBox` is mutually exclusive you can check the `SelectedIndex` property which will return the index of the currently focused list box item since the focused choice is also the currently selected one.

Comment: @aus_lacy I have two `ListBox`es next to each other. So in both lists, an item can be selected - this won't work. Or am I misunderstanding what you say?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what you wished to do. My solution is to locate which item in the given `ListBox` is selected. Normally you would want to check which `ListBoxItem` is the currently focused UI element and then determine which `ListBox` that item belongs to in order to determine which `ListBox` has the current focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
public ListBox FocusedListBox()
{
    DependencyObject currentObject = (UIElement)FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

    while(currentObject != Application.Current.MainWindow)
    {
        if(currentObject == listBox1 || currentObject == listBox2)
        {
            return currentObject as ListBox;
        }
        else
        {
            currentObject = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(currentObject);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The reason for walking the logical tree is that it is (more than likely) not the listbox itself that has focus but a child object of the listbox.

Comment: Actually `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);` returns `null` every time.

Comment: I assumed `this` was the view/control containing the listboxes.  That may have been an incorrect assumption.  You could try `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(Application.Current.MainWindow)` instead or Keyboard.FocusedElement.

Comment: Actually, the list boxes *are* contained in a user control that's within a tab control that's within a grid of the main window, and the value of `this` is actually the user control. I really have no idea what's going on...

Comment: I found a solution based on your solution, so I will accept your answer and thank you for your help.